# Unable to mount an SMB share from cron

Tags: macos, bash, mount, smb

I have a script to temporarily mount an SMB share and copy some files that get generated for my team.

It works find locally, but fails to mount the remote share when run from `cron`. I am not including the script as the commands in question should be evident from the outputs below.

Local operation output:

```
$ get-reports.sh 
Tue Feb 18 16:14:05 EST 2020
+ whoami
gtarsa
+ id
uid=1234567(gtarsa) gid=1234567(#######) groups=1234567(#######),<usual Apple groups>
+ /sbin/umount /Users/gtarsa/reports
+ /sbin/mount -t smbfs //engsrv/reports /Users/gtarsa/reports
+ find /Users/gtarsa/reports -iname '*gtarsa*' -exec cp '{}' /Users/gtarsa/Downloads/reports ';'
+ /sbin/umount /Users/gtarsa/reports
+ set +x
$
```

Cron result:

```
$ cat ~/Downloads/reports/copy.log 
Tue Feb 18 12:20:00 EST 2020
+ whoami
gtarsa
+ id
uid=1234567(gtarsa) gid=1234567(#######) groups=1234567(#######),<usual Apple groups>
+ /sbin/umount /Users/gtarsa/reports
+ /sbin/mount -t smbfs //engsrv/reports /Users/gtarsa/reports
mount_smbfs: server rejected the connection: Authentication error
+ echo '? Unable to mount Reports Share'
? Unable to mount Reports Share
+ exit 1
$
```

I have tried explicitly specifying connection credentials (as described in `man mount_smbfs`) with no success.  I am running script manually when I need it, but would prefer to have it run periodically on its own.

Something is different in the `cron` environment from my interactive environment, but I have not been able to discern what. Google searches for answers come up with lots of "How to mount a share from the command line", but not from `cron`. Ideas and insight welcome.

Comment: It generates an authentication error.  How are you passing the username/password?  See `man mount_smbfs` for more details.

Comment: In this example, I am assuming that what works in my terminal window should work with `cron`; so, I am not passing any authentication information--it defaults to the correct information in my terminal window.  Having said that, I experimented with passing explcit credentials as described in `man mount_smbfs`. Passing the correct credentials explicitly gives the same error.

Comment: If passing the credentials gives the same error either you have a problem with the credentials or you have an issue with the way the URI is formatted..but I can't tell from all the way over here...

Comment: What does the cron entry look like?  Also what is the path to the cron file?  Cron does not run using the same environment as your shell by default.  Also, unless otherwise specified cron jobs are usually run as root

Comment: Is the Apple login the *same* as the login for the SMB server?  What if you just do a simple `open smb://<smbserver>/share/path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some things are different in the `cron` environment from your `gtarsa` environment. [You can check the `cron` user environment for yourself using this "recipe"](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/WhatIsCronEnvironment.md).

Since you can run your script manually, it seems likely you've set up your Samba passwords and permissions appropriately.

You've chosen not to share your `crontab` entry, but I've `mount`ed and `umount`ed my Samba shares from a `cron` script with lines in my `crontab` like this:

```bsh
25 * * * * /sbin/mount -t smbfs //user:password@SambaServer/sharename /Users/seamus/SmbSrv01 

35 * * * * /sbin/umount /Users/seamus/SmbSrv01
```

This assumes a mountpoint declared (`mkdir`) at `/Users/seamus/SmbSrv01`

Since the `cron` user's path is not the same as `gtarsa`, you should check that you're using full path specifications to everything that's not in the `cron` user's PATH... or just everything if you're not sure.

Also NOTE: Putting `userid` and `password` in a script or a `crontab` as I've done here is something you should **not** do. Less insecure is putting the `userid` and `password` in `~/.bash_profile`; e.g.:

```
export MOUNTUSERID="some_user" # where "some_user" is you, or a userid with Samba privileges 
export MOUNTUSERPWD="some_passwd" # "some_passwd" is "some_user" Samba password
```

Add these lines to the bottom of `~/.bash_profile`, and use these environment vars with the `mount` command in your script. Before you run the script, reload `~/.bash_profile` to pick up the environment variables you've just declared:

```bsh
source ~/.bash_profile
```

`<redundant>`You've chosen not to share your `crontab` entry`</redundant>`, but if you've not already done so you could help yourself by directing `stderr` from your script to a file for post-mortem analysis. In your `crontab`:

```
* * * * * /full/path/to/script >> copy.log 2>&1
```

will capture anything output to `stderr` in the file copy.log

Finally, if you're running your script under the `@reboot` spec, you should probably put a `sleep` command before you try to `mount`.

If none of this helps, please edit your Q to add your `crontab` entries, and as much of your script as possible and relevant.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to issue a mount command.

Comment: @Allan: I take your point. I think there are cases where `sudo` is required to successfully execute a `mount` command, but my Mojave systems seems to be happy without it. I'll revise my answer, and thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks, Seamus, for the complete answer.  I experimented with the credentials and learned that, at least in my environment, that the username needs to be explicitly specified, apparently it is different in `cron`.  With an explicit username I found I did not have to specify a password at all.

Comment: @GregTarsa: Hmmm... that's odd. I can't think of any reason you'd authenticate differently in `cron`. But I'm glad you cleared the hurdle. Let us know if anything else comes up.